# Is there a way to expand a one-dimensional Array into a 2D Array with the original values in the [0] index of the 2D Array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an Array with Category Names, but now i Need to assign a few Counters to each Category.
Is there a way to expand my 1D-Array to a 2D-Array in C#?

Thanks for helping!

Edit:

```
PerformanceCounterCategory[] categories;
        categories = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories();

        string[] categoryNames = new string[categories.Length];
        string[] categoryNames_en = new string[categories.Length];

        for (int objX = 0; objX < categories.Length; objX++)
        {
            categoryNames[objX] = categories[objX].CategoryName;
        }
        Array.Sort(categoryNames);

        for (int objX = 0; objX < categories.Length; objX++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,4} - {1}", objX + 1, categoryNames[objX]);
        }
```

I have the Array categoryNames with all the Names of the Categories, but in every Category there are a few Counters which i want to assign to their Category somehow...

Comment: no, arrays aren't resizable data structures

Comment: Can you perhaps give a concrete example of what you want to achieve? Coz you may be better off using other data structures like List or Dictionary

Comment: @jmc  I edited my Question with an example and what i want to do

Comment: I don't see a 2-dimensional array in your code

Comment: Are you asking how to add another column to your array?

Comment: @Serv thats because there is None yet, but i want to create one out of the one-dimensional "categoryNames", where every string of "categoryNames" is then the [0]-index of the new 2D Array

Comment: @xK3v please describe the actual problem you are trying to solve, not how you think it will be solved. If you have a list of performance counter categories and want to get the counter values for a few of them, array resizing is irrelevant.

Comment: I've given you one example on how you can create a 2-dimensional array from a 1-dimensional array. This should get you started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use Array.Copy since the source and destination array do not have the same dimensions.

Furthermore, you can't expand arrays in C#, since they are initialized with a fixed size.

What you can do is create a new array with a second dimonesion and copy the values over and set the second dimension to a default value.

```
void Main()
{
    int[] sourceCollection = new [] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} ;

    var result = CopyArrayValues(sourceCollection, 2);
    result.Dump();
}
//create a new 2d array
T[,] CopyArrayValues<T>(T[] DataSource, int SecondLength)
{
    //Initialize the new array
    var Target = new T[DataSource.Length, SecondLength];
    //Copy values over
    for (int i = 0; i < DataSource.Length; i++)
    {
        Target[i, 0] = DataSource[i];
    }

    return Target;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok for you to have array of arrays, you can do something along this pattern:

```
int[] sourceCollection = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
int[][] arr = sourceCollection.Select(i => Enumerable.Range(i, 4).ToArray()).ToArray();
```